# Hibernate wrong generate auto id increment

Tags: java, hibernate

I am not sure what happened but one day Hibernate started to wrong generate auto ID in Osoba.

What I mean is when I add person(Osoba) he gets ID 60, next one gets 64 but it should get 61... How can I fix that? So it will increment by 1 no by 4 or other like this is now...  Also how can I "reset" ID value? I would like to clean whole table, and start counting from ID 1

```
<class name="Osoba" table="DANEOSOBOWE">

        <id name="id" type="int" column="id">
                <generator class="native"/>
                </id>
```

---

```
public class Osoba implements Interface {

    private int id;
    private String imie;
    private String nazwisko;
    private String email;
    private String telefon;
    private String uczelnia;
    private String doswiadczenie;    
    private String skadSlyszal;
    private List zainteresowania = new ArrayList(); 

  public Osoba(){ // domyslny    
  }

  // konstruktor zeby mozna bylo sobie w jednej linijce dodawac osobe
   public Osoba(String imie1, String nazwisko1, String telefon1, String email1, String uczelnia1, String doswiadczenie1, String skadSlyszal1 ){
       this.imie = imie1;
       this.nazwisko = nazwisko1;
       this.email = email1;
       this.telefon = telefon1;
       this.uczelnia = uczelnia1;
       this.doswiadczenie = doswiadczenie1;
       this.skadSlyszal = skadSlyszal1;
       }
```

Comment: "native" means that it asks the database to generate the ID. If there are gaps in the ID sequence, then it's because the database has chosen to do so.

Comment: I tried to delete whole sequence in postresql also I deleted whole tables and created new ones but it didnt help

Answer (score 2):

Native: This generation strategy is the *default*. It simply chooses the primary key generation strategy that is the default for the database in question, which quite typically is `IDENTITY`, although it might be `TABLE` or `SEQUENCE` depending upon how the database is configured. The native strategy is typically recommended, as it makes your code and your applications most portable.

For example: In Mysql if you have primary key column as `auto_increment`, the db will be updated using this strategy.

Answer (score 2):

Using annotations -

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="course_seq")
@SequenceGenerator(
    name="course_seq",
    sequenceName="course_sequence",
    allocationSize=1
)
private int id;
```

allocation size of 1 will increment it by 1.

Comment: But it sequences it is written to increment by 1 but still it doesnt do it, also Id rather to use map files right now

Comment: If you are in the development phase set this - <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but increment was 32 instead of 4 as for you: I solved it by closing `sessionFactory`.  I'm using H2 database, so here is link to documentation:
http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#set_cache_size

Where it says:

> The cache is the number of pre-allocated numbers. If the system crashes without closing the database, at most this many numbers are lost. The default cache size is 32. To disable caching, use the cache size 1 or lower.

So when I didn't close `sessionFactory` in my `Main` method, the increment was 32, but when I started closing it, it worked. I re-created database, and it worked. And when I looked to `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SEQUENCES` table, which is the table with properties of sequence generation of my database , I saw that magic `CACHE_SIZE = 32`.

So every time database was not closed properly, the sequence lost exactly 32 numbers.